# Why am I getting object object in my input box react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck on making component work.

[image: console.log and localhost image]

I think it's something to do with `handleChange` but I can't figure it out.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function FindCountry({ setNews }) {
    const [idInput, setIdInput] = useState('');
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState('');
    function getCountryID() {
        const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${idInput}&apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_GIPHY_KEY}`;
        fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('We have data!', res);
                setIdInput(res);
                setErrors('');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
                setErrors('Invalid Input');
            });
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
        setIdInput(e.target.value); 
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        getCountryID();
    }
```

Comment: `setIdInput(res)` in `getCountryID` sets the whole response object as the state, which is rendered as `[object Object]` when converted to a string.

Comment: That make sense. Thank you Emile!